# How do I change the format I get a message in with gmail api

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, gmail-api

I'm trying to change the format of the email I get from the inbox, but I don't know how to do that:

```
const email = Gmail.Users.Messages.get("me", id, {format: no idea what to put here})
```

The documentation says this, but idk how to get those types in my code (I'm using apps script)

[image: image of the api]

Comment: Try one of the formats in the enums in your image

Comment: The documentation keeps reverting back to the RESTful docs.  As your using AppScript it's expecting an "optional parameters" Object as shown by the "intellisense" and for which I cannot find the docs.  But maybe try: `{ format : "minimal" }`.  Also I don't think you can _change_ the format so much as control what is returned to you by the call to `get()`

Answer (score 0):

You can review the different types of format msgs using this quick sample:

```js
function msgFormats() {
  ["minimal", "full", "raw", "metadata"].forEach(format => {
    const msg = Gmail.Users.Messages.get('me', msgId, { format: format })
    console.log(msg)
  })
}
```

###### **Documentation**:

- [Format Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/Format)